# Expected expression in seemingly unrelated method?

Tags: ios, xcode, methods

I have two methods and the second ones empty as I haven't gotten into filling the code yet. My problem is that the last few lines of code in the first expression seems to break the second even though I can't think of a reason why as they are completely unrelated. I get an `expected expression` error under the IBAction of the second method.

```
- (IBAction)showResultsFromYesterday:(id)sender {

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [NSDateComponents new];
todayComponents.year = 2014;
todayComponents.month = 2;
todayComponents.day = 16;
todayComponents.hour = 4;
todayComponents.minute = 59;
todayComponents.second = 50;

NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:todayComponents];

NSDateComponents *offset = [NSDateComponents new];
offset.day = -1;
NSDate *yesterday = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offset toDate:today options:0];

PFQuery *yesterdayUserCountQuery = [PFUser query];
[yesterdayUserCountQuery whereKey:@"createdAt" greaterThanOrEqualTo:yesterday];
[yesterdayUserCountQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int userCount, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The count request succeeded. Log the count
        //     NSLog(@"There are %d users", userCount);
    } else {
        // The request failed
    }
    NSString *yesterdayNumberOfUsers = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d", userCount ];
    self.numberOfUsers.text = yesterdayNumberOfUsers;
}

- (IBAction)showResultsFromLastWeek:(id)sender {


}
```

When i remove all the code for the PFQuery, the error goes away. I have no idea why its causing an error in the other method.

Comment: *Carefully* count your `{` and `}` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close the block you passed to `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:`. You need a closing `}`.